# New session bean for entity classes - NetBeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans-8, java-ee-7, glassfish-5

I am following this tutorial: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html

I can add the entity classes but when I move on to the next step of adding session beans, NetBeans won't allow it and gives me this error:

*Cannot be generated because EJB Lite classes are not available on project classpath*

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: The tutorial says you need to use Netbeans 6.8 or 6.9, this looks like a very old tutorial to me, maybe you should look for something more recent.

Comment: I know. It is for a class that I am taking and I have to use this tutorial for the final project and it has been a nightmare.

Comment: Okay. The code should be IDE independent anyway. Can you create a class file and create the EJB manually?